# Upgrade the drupal 7.88 to drupal 10.1.1

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-10

I have update the my drupal website 7.88 to 10.1.1. It's all process using composer. But i have facing some issue in admin panel. 
I have checked the drupal version is upgrade or not. Using command line.

Using this command :: composer show drupal/core-recommended
Showing this message :: versions : * 10.1.1

In command line showing the drupal version is upgrade.

But also i have checked in drupal admin panel. But it's not showing the upgrade version.
This URL :: admin/reports/updates
But still showing the old version 7.88.

So how to resolve this issue? Please help and give me a suggestion for this.

I have used the command in drupal official website for version 10.1.1.

In command line showing the drupal version is upgrade.
Using this command :: composer show drupal/core-recommended
Showing this message :: versions : * 10.1.1

But also i have checked in drupal admin panel. But it's not showing the upgrade version.
This URL :: admin/reports/updates
But still showing the old version 7.88.

Comment: It's a long path and I'm afraid 7 to 8 step will be the most difficult.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please share the step document. So i can follow this document.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no such document. You can start reading here : https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrading-from-drupal-6-or-drupal-7

Comment: Basic steps are rebuild the site in D10. Use the various migrate modules to bring over the content.

Answer (score 1):

There has been significant changes from D7 to D10 and your site probably should be migrated to D10 using a new D10 install versus just updating in the UI or via composer. You should look at the Drupal migration modules https://www.drupal.org/docs/core-modules-and-themes/core-modules/migrate-drupal-module and the documentation for upgrading a site https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal. If you are comforatble with command line doing the migration via drush in my opion is best. https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrading-from-drupal-6-or-drupal-7/upgrade-using-drush